# Javascript disable button after click, but form doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that disables the button after one click perfectly, but the problem is, is the form doesn't submit then.  How do I disabled the button after one click and still have the form submit.

Code

```
<input id="submitbtn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit for Payment" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#submitbtn').one('click', function() {  
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deferring the button disabling code until after the form submit event fires might be your best option. You can do this a few ways. If you only have one button that you want to disable, add a `submit` event listener to the form and disable it in the callback. Another simple approach is to use setTimeout which runs after 0 milliseconds.

```
setTimeout( () => $(this).attr('disabled','disabled') , 0);
```

Also, if you're using a version of jQuery that supports `.prop()`, I'd recommend using that instead of `attr`. Example: `$(this).prop('disabled', true)`.

Comment: Ok great, just keep in mind the asynchronous nature of doing it the setTimeout way. Also, take note of the context of `this` with relation to the arrow function (`() => {}`) as it is different than standard functions. More reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the onsubmit attribute to your form and put the code to disable the button there, so you disable the button but the first submit has already happened:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction();">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(){
        $('#submitbtn').attr('disabled','disabled');
        // my submit code here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `myFunction()` defined?

Comment: myFunction is the function where to put the code for disabling the button...I thought it was obvious just updating the answer to add it compelte.

Comment: That won't work. You have the code that disables the submit button inside an event handler. But the event handler won't be added until after the user clicks the submit button, so the code will never run until the user tries to submit the form a second time.

Comment: Get rid of the `.one()` function and just disable the submit button.

Comment: thanks I know, I just didn't have time to do that, just copied the code from inside the previous answer after received a comment about the function...I was just doing the same...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $('#submitbtn').on('click', function() {  
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $("#formID").submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="submitbtn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit for Payment" />
```

Comment: The `submit()` function has to be called on a `<form>` not a submit button.

Comment: It should be `$(this.form).submit()`. But the button isn't inside a form.

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to actually use `form ID`. Thanks.